# How to change the Gutenberg Group Block's "Inner blocks use content width" Toggle to Off/False as Default

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

When you wrap a new set of blocks in the core/group block the "Inner blocks use content width" toggle switch defaults to true. There is an object attribute showing called `layout` for that block. I'm assuming that I can update the settings on the `layout` attribute like I can with the `align` attribute.

Here is how I'm updating the `align` attribute:

```
const { addFilter } = wp.hooks;
const { assign, merge } = lodash;

function filterCoverBlockAlignments(settings, name) {
  if (name === 'core/group') {
    return assign({}, settings, {
      attributes: assign( {}, settings.attributes, {  align: {
        type: 'string', default: 'wide'
      } } ),
    });
    // console.log({ settings, name });
  }
  return settings;
}

addFilter(
  'blocks.registerBlockType',
  'intro-to-filters/cover-block/alignment-settings',
  filterCoverBlockAlignments,
);
```

The above works so I assume updating the layout's default would be similar, but either I don't have the syntax for an object type correct, or possibly you can't update the layout object like you can update the align string. This is what I tried for the function:

```
function filterCoverBlockAlignments(settings, name) {
  if (name === 'core/group') {
    return assign({}, settings, {
      attributes: assign( {}, settings.attributes, {  layout: {
        type: 'object', [{
          type: 'default'
        }]
      } } ),
    });
    // console.log({ settings, name });
  }
  return settings;
}
```

In short I'm trying to get the blocks `layer` attribute (which is an object and not a string) have it's attribute of `type` to default to "default" instead of "constrain".

Answer (score 0):

I mean yes, you could solve it by filtering. What I would suggest however, is making a block-variation. Then setting that block-variation as the default. That block variation then can have any of your settings you like to set. Quite simple in theory.

> By default, all variations will show up in the Inserter in addition to the regular block type item. However, setting the isDefault flag for any of the variations listed will override the regular block type in the Inserter.

source: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-variations/

```js
wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation( 'core/group', {
    name: 'custom-group',
    // this one is important, so you don't end up with an extra block
    isDefault: true,
    // and here you add all your attributes
    attributes: { providerNameSlug: 'custom' },
} );
```

Here is a slightly cleaner variant (using destructuring), if you have more code:

```
// extract the function from wp.blocks into a variable
const { registerBlockVariation } = wp.blocks;

// register like above
registerBlockVariation();
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative approach to the overall task but even with this approach I don't know the proper syntax for the object type "Layout" to change it so the check box is unchecked by default.